# CSS: issues about my responsive header design

Tags: html, css, search, menu, header

I am creating a header which has menu and search function.

In my responsive design, I have menu icon on left side, and search icon on right side.
[image: navigation]

When I click search icon, it works. Search options slide from right to left.

But when I click menu icon, search options appear from right to left.

> I want to slide menu from left to right, when I click menu icon.

I am using sass compiler in VS code.

I am glad if someone helps me out.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round");
#sidebarMenu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-1500px);
  transform: translateX(-1500px);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  background: #000000;
}

.sidebarMenuInner {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebarMenuInner li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebarMenuInner li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~#sidebarMenu {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

.sidebarIconToggle {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 18px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}

.spinner {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.horizontal {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.diagonal.part-1 {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}

.diagonal.part-2 {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.horizontal {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.diagonal.part-1 {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin-top: 8px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.diagonal.part-2 {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  margin-top: -9px;
}

#sidebarSearch {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(1500px);
  transform: translateX(1500px);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  background: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebarIconSearch i {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~#sidebarSearch {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.search-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
}

.search_text {
  outline: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60%;
  border: solid 3px #fff;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.tag-list {
  color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

.tag-list li {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 2px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 16%;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.Category dt {
  background: #fff;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.Category dt img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.Category dd {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.Category-list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
  -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.Day-box {
  outline: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  border: solid 3px #fff;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  background: #2D2524;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

.main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.mainInner {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.mainInner div display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 3em;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 1.25px;

}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
<label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
          <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
          <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
          <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
        </label>
<div id="sidebarMenu">
  <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Log out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>




<input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarSearch" id="openSidebarSearch">
<label for="openSidebarSearch" class="sidebarIconSearch">
        <i class="fas fa-search search_icon"></i>
      </label>

<div id="sidebarSearch">
  <div class="search-erea">
    <div class="search-title">Enter the name of event</div>
    <input type="text" class="search_text">
    <div class="search-title">Choose tags</div>
    <ul class="tag-list">
      <li>Tag</li>
      <li>Tag</li>
      <li>Tag</li>
      <li>Tag</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="tag-list">
      <li>Tag</li>
      <li>Tag</li>
      <li>Tag</li>
      <li>Tag</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="search-erea">
    <div class="search-title">Categorys</div>
    <div class="Category-list">
      <dl class="Category">
        <dt><img src="./martini.png" alt="bar-img"></dt>
        <dd>bar</dd>
      </dl>
      <dl class="Category">
        <dt><img src="./beer.png" alt="pub-img"></dt>
        <dd>pub</dd>
      </dl>
      <dl class="Category">
        <dt><img src="./dj.png" alt="club-img"></dt>
        <dd>club</dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="search-erea">
    <div class="search-title">Day</div>
    <input type="text" class="Day-box">
  </div>

</div>




<div id='center' class="main center">
  <div class="mainInner">
    <div>Main image</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! : )  Consider creating a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - so we can be more help.

Comment: but there is no any search icon in your header

Comment: @Ranjithv I included icon right there <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarSearch" id="openSidebarSearch">
  <label for="openSidebarSearch" class="sidebarIconSearch">
    <i class="fas fa-search search_icon"></i>
  </label>
I cannot figure out why I need empty header div at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Target your Checkbox

```
input[type="checkbox"].openSidebarSearch //Target with Class


input[type="checkbox"].openSidebarSearch:checked ~ #sidebarSearch {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
          transform: translateX(0);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/dgxye752/3/